# Couchbase - Splitting a JSON object into many key-value entries - performance improvement?

Tags: json, performance, couchbase

Say my Couchbase DB has millions of user objects, each user object contains some primitive fields (score, balance etc.)
And say I read & write most of those fields on every server request.

I see 2 options of storing the User object in Couchbase:

1. A single JSON object mapped to a user key (e.g. user_555)
2. Mapping each field into a separate entry (e.g. score_555 and balance_555)

Option 1 - Single CB lookup, JSON parsing 
Option 2 - Twice the lookups, less parsing if any

How can I tell which one is better in terms of performance?
What if I had 3 fields? what if 4? does it make a difference?

Thanks

Eyal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about your data structure and access patterns first before worrying if json parsing or extra lookups will add overhead to your system.

From my perspective and experience I would try to model documents based upon logical object groupings, I would store 'user' attributes together.  If you were to store each field separately you'd have to do a series of lookups if you ever wanted to provide a client or service with a full overview of the player profile.

I've used Couchbase as the main data store for a social mobile game, we store 90% of user data in a user document, this contains all the relevant fields such as score,level,progress etc.  For the majority of operations such as a new score or upgrades we want to be dealing with the whole User object in the application layer so it makes sense to inflate the user object from the cb document, alter/read what we need and then persist it again if there have been changes.

The only time we have id references to other documents is in the form of player purchases where we have an array of ids that each reference a separate purchase. We do this as we wanted to have richer information on each purchase (date of transaction,transaction id,product type etc) that isn't relevant to the user document as when a purchase is made we verify it's legitimate and then add to the User inventory and create the separate purchase document.

So our structure is:

UserDoc:

-Fields specific to a User (score,level,progress,friends,inventory)

-Arrays of IDS pointing to specific purchases

The only time I'd consider splitting out some specific fields as you outlined above would be if your user document got seriously large but I think it'd be best to divide documents up per groupings of data as opposed to specific fields.

Hope that helped!

Comment: The example of your UserDoc, fields and array of 'foreign keys' was exactly what I needed to hear, that this is the way to go instead of splitting my object into many entries...